# WordPress select dropdown value display with loop

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I want to show only the number of posts in that category / term when I select the category / term from the dropdown. By default, all the posts in the loop will show.

Comment: Your supplied WP code query will output all post type `post`s matching your `tax_query` based on your `$query_object` values. You are then doing `get_the_terms()` for every result in the first loop. If has $term and has no parent, you are then looping each of these results for every previous loop result. Please elaborate a little more as your current code is very intense as a query.  I'm sure we can find a faster query to help you out.

Comment: Please see my update & please help.....