# Wordpress two custom_post_type one taxonomy

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type, custom-wordpress-pages, custom-taxonomy

I create two custom post_type. The name of the custom post is-

> **1. Brand**
> **2. Ethical**

And I have created a taxonomy. The name of the taxonomy is - **Pharma**. The common taxonomy of the two custom posts is one **(pharma)**.

Now I want, on one page -

> **1. Just to display all the names of Pharma Taxonomy.**
> **2. I would like to display only brand custom posts under Pharma Taxonomy.**
> **3. I would like to count only the post of brand custom post under pharma taxonomy.**

All right. But when I just call the **brand custom post_type** with **Pharma Taxonomy** then the **ethic custom post** also becomes a call. I want a solution.

```php
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'brand',
    'taxonomy' => 'pharma',
    'order'     => 'ASC',
    'posts_per_page'  => -1,
);

$query = new WP_Term_Query($args);
foreach ($query->get_terms() as $term) : ?>
    <div class="item_wrap">
        <h2><a href="<?php echo esc_url(get_term_link($term->term_id)); ?>"><?php echo $term->name; ?></a></h2>

        <span class="count"><?php echo $term->count; ?> <?php _e('brands'); ?></span>
    </div>
<?php endforeach;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`WP_Term_Query` does **NOT** take `'post_type'` argument [`Here's a list of valid arguments`<sup>Docs</sup>](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/WP_Term_Query/__construct/#parameters). However, you could add a [`WP_Query`<sup>Docs</sup>](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#taxonomy-parameters) inside your `foreach` statement. Like this:

```php
$pharm_args = array(
    'taxonomy'  => 'pharma',
    'orderby'   => 'name',
    'order'     => 'ASC',
);

$pharm_query = new WP_Term_Query($pharm_args);


foreach ($pharm_query->get_terms() as $term) :
    $count_args = array(
        'post_type'      => 'brand',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'tax_query'      => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => $term->taxonomy,
                'field'    => 'slug',
                'terms'    => $term->slug,
            ),
        )
    );
    $count_term_in_cpt = new WP_Query($count_args);
    if ($count_term_in_cpt->found_posts) {
?>
        <div class='item_wrap'>
            <h2><a href="<?php echo esc_url(get_term_link($term->term_id)); ?>"><?php echo $term->name; ?></a></h2>

            <span class='count'><?php echo $count_term_in_cpt->found_posts; _e('brands'); ?></span>
        </div>
<?php
    }
    wp_reset_postdata();
endforeach;
```

Which will output this:

[image]

Comment: Excellent. It's working. Answer iaccepted. Thank you very much.

Comment: Please solve my other problem? Below is the link-
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70595785/wordpress-select-dropdown-value-display-with-loop